# Is there any speed differences using functions in the query or setting as a variable?

Tags: mysql

I am using a `between` on dates, so is it slower to do this:

```
select sum(amount) from my_table 
where pur_date between DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR), INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
and DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY);
```

Or is it faster to do this:

```
set @startdt = (select DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR), INTERVAL 1 DAY));
set @enddt = (select DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY));

select sum(amount) from my_table where pur_date between @startdt and @enddt;
```

Or does it not make a difference? The reason I ask is, I am not sure if the functions get run for every row if they are put directly in the query as opposed to setting them as variables.

I am hoping that you could straighten this out for me!

Comment: Doesn't make much difference.  But why not benchmark it yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First one is faster.

More are select statements, more sluggish is program in execution.

Comment: What if your looking through 10+ million rows, which I am doing.

Comment: @RyanNaddy there are no direct differences between SET and SELECT. However SELECT's ability to make multiple assignments in one shot does give it a slight speed advantage over SET. See here: http://vyaskn.tripod.com/differences_between_set_and_select.htm

Comment: If the function's value does not depend on the row, in most cases optimiser will calculate its value before execution.